# Who are the truth-teller dwarves?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

**Infomation/Story**

Your prince is bewitched and asleep.

You have to feed him the good apples (from the truth-teller dwarves) to save him.

But be careful. Only the truth-teller dwarves, who only tell the truth, have good apples.

The liar dwarves, who only lie, have poisoned apples.

If you can find all three good apples, your prince will be released.

**Let's start then...**

- Red Dwarf said:    Black has a good apple.
- Orange Dwarf said: I dug up a lump of gold!
- Yellow Dwarf said: Orange is in my group.
- Green Dwarf said:  The weather on the mountain is so whimsical. Yesterday, we
  had a huge rainstorm.
- Blue Dwarf said:   White isn't in my group.
- Black Dwarf said:  Green isn't in my group.
- White Dwarf said:  Red's apple is a good one indeed.

So, which ones are the good apples?

Comment: By groups do the dwarves mean Group with Good Apples and Group with Bad Apples?

Comment: Cannot say that

Comment: Hey, this is from Phi Brain!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The truth telling dwarves are:

> Orange, Blue, and Yellow

Because:

> Let's break down one sentence in particular:
>  "X isn't in my group" is said by two dwarves.
>  Either:
>  1. The dwarf speaking is telling the truth, which means that X is a liar, or
>  2. The dwarf speaking is a liar, which means that X is also a liar
>  Either way, X is a liar.
>
>  From this, we can deduce that White and Green are liars because Black and Blue said so.
>  Knowing about white means that red has a poison apple, and so is a liar.
>  knowing about red means that black has a poison apple, and so is a liar.
>
>  Now we know that White, Green, Red, and Black are Liars. There are three remaining dwarves, and three remaining good apples. By elimination, Orange, Yellow, and Blue have the good apples!

Comment: Omg that was to good...I diden't think somone could solve it :)